# How fake function framework can be used when 2 processes are involved in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, testing

I am having some C code (**my test object**) which is interacting with some external library. To do some component testing I have written a **stub for external library**. I am using **google test framework** to write test cases. I am seding some signals between my test object and google tests which means I am having 2 processes. 1 for google test and 1 for my test object. Everything works fine.

Now instead of using **stubbed library** I want to use **Fake Function Framework (fff.h)** which auto generate stubbes at compile time. I know how to generate stubbes but the problem is that it will work if we have a single process but I want to use it for multiple processes. As the stubbed functions are generated at compile time is there any way to access them from another process?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: In other words, could you elaborate on how you tried to use the FFF and what errors/problems did you encounter

Comment: I have written a stub for external library which took some weeks. fff is used to auto generate stub functions which will reduce some overhead work. There will be no need to write big stub libraries. I am trying to understand it how this framework can be used when 2 processes are involved.

Comment: --> What have you tried with it and what *real* problem are you facing?

Comment: As I described fff will generate stub function, they will be generated in my test_process during compile time. I am sending signal to my test object who will process the signal and call the external library function which I have stubbed. Now the problem is that these stubbed functions are not available in the second process.

Comment: And why can't you stub them in the same way for the second process?

Comment: Because stub functions will be generated at compile time by using macros which can only be written in test file not in the test object which is a real code.

Comment: See my answer below. Stubs don't have to be in the test file. Stubs can be written into seperate files that are independently compiled (to an archive, for example) and then linked into your test binary along with you test code and real code. We are using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your fff stubs can be compiled into an archive (static library) and then statically linked into your unit testing binaries. There is no reason why you couldn't share that same library with multiple unit test binaries.

Compiling the stubs into a dynamic library could also be done but sharing the library dynamically with multiple test binaries typically doesn't make sense since your units should be unit tested independently of each other. The stubs are probably not re-entrant.